# How to avoid hoisting state to an app-level?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, hoisting

I have an Android app in Jetpack Compose. I have a screen where the user can create a new player.

[image: New Player screen]

On this screen, the user can type in a Player name and select a color. Then, the user presses the checkmark in the top right corner and saves the player into the database. My problem here is that this screen is created using an app-wide `Scaffold`. The top app bar is a `TopAppBar` and thus the `onClick` function of the checkmark button doesn't have access to the player name and color from the screen, since the screen is a screen rendered using a `NavHost`.

When is the cleanest approach for this situation? I've come up with a possible solution.

The solution is to have a `var player = remember { mutableStateOf(Player()) }` on my `App()` composable and then hoist the `onPlayerChange: (player: Player) -> Unit` event handler up, but that seems very dirty to me.

I have asked ChatGPT, and it came up with a shared ViewModel solution, but that would mean that when I press the checkmark to save the player, I would have to acquire an instance of the ViewModel inside the onClick listener of the button, which doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: "I would have to acquire an instance of the ViewModel inside the onClick" - what's the issue? Also consider a scaffold per screen instead which is very common in large apps to simplify state management.

Comment: @DerekK I would consider that, however, with the multiple Scaffold solution, I ran into a different problem I couldn't find a good fix for. I use a `NavHost` as the content for my scaffold, because I have a bottom navigation bar. When the user navigates to this "add player" screen, I simply hide the bottom bar and make the top bar appear (while re-using the scaffold). However, if I had a Scaffold for each screen, I would need to have two NavHosts (one inside the main screen scaffold and another one as the main app NavHost). I would maybe prefer having a single navigation in my app, not two...

Comment: @DerekK Also, are you saying that acquiring a ViewModel instance inside an onClick listener is okay? How would I acquire the ViewModel inside the onClick? I use Koin for dependency injection by the way.

Comment: @DerekK okay, I have found out it's a lot more complicated than I thought. Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is a nice transition animation between my screens. I want the top bar to appear from the top and then slide back out from the top when the user leaves the screen. I believe this is only accomplishable by using a single scaffold or having the top bar shared between the screens somehow. Currently, I have not found a good way to separate the screen logic and also I have no way to save the player from the Scaffold when only the screen has access to the ViewModel.

Comment: Animations are in fact the issue in the multiple Scaffold approach, but there is always a trade-off. Sharing state between multiple screens and having nice screen transitions at the same time has always been tricky.